# Method That Takes Super Class As Parameter And Manipulates Sub Classes

Tags: java, polymorphism, aggregation

I have class "A" that has two arrayLists of objects of two classes "BC" and "BD". BC and BD inherit from the abstract class "B".

So what I am struggling to do is, I want to make a single add(); method that takes B objects as parameter and adds BC objects if the parameter is BC type, and  add BD objects if the parameter is BD type. Is there a correct way to do this or should I make seperate add methods?

```
   public class A
   {
        private ArrayList<BC> bcArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<BD> bcArrayList= new ArrayList<>();

        public void add(ArrayList<B> bArrayList)
        {
            //m = create new object of type, either BC or BD;
            bArrayList.add(m);
        }
   }
```

Comment: I don’t understand your example, the parameter is a list that you add an object to instead of adding to one of the instance variables?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear example, all I want is to not use two add methods, one for bcArrayList and one for bdArrayList, instead I want to pass one of these arrays to one add method and get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you want to add multiple objects from a list then have one method that takes a `List<B>` and use `instanceof`

```
public void add(List<B> bList) {
    for (B b : bList) {
        if (b instanceof BC) {
            bcArrayList.add((BC)b);
        }
        if (b instanceof BD) {
            bdArrayList.add((BD)b);
        }
    }         
}
```

But for adding single objects I think using method overloading is the cleanest way to do it

```
public void add(BC b) {
    bcArrayList.add(b);
}

public void add(BD b) {
    bdArrayList.add(b);
}
```

Of course you can add them all to your class and use them like this

```
A a = new A();
a.add(new BC());
a.add(new BD());
List<B> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new BC());
list.add(new BD());
a.add(list);
```

Comment: I think overloading will be a solution to my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the getClass method i.e. m.getClass().

Comment: I am aware of this method. However, I've heard that it is a bad practice to use getClass or instanceof, is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: Try adding a field for the type of class, such as a boolean isBC.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do that then I imagine you could do something like this:

```java
public class A {
     private List<B> bcArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     private List<B> bdArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

     public void add(List<B> bArrayList) {
         for (B item : bArrayList){

             if (item.getClass() == BC.class) {
                 bcArrayList.add(item);

             } else if (item.getClass() == BD.class){
                 bdArrayList.add(item);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

That said, are you sure that you really need that?

Why not put them in the same list (they are all objects of type `B`) and have subclasses `BC` and `BD` behave differently as needed. That's what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: I don't want to do any bad practices, so is there a way to make this in a good OOP way?

Comment: You wanted specifically to split objects into different lists depending on their class, at some point you'll have to check that class. The real question is why you want to do that, since you tagged this question with `polymorphism`.

Comment: Won't putting them in the same arrayList cause a problem when I have to call  some methods of their own?

Comment: And even then how will I add BD or BC objects depending on what is requested with one add method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way to do that is using the instanceof operator.

```
   public class A
   {
        private ArrayList<BC> bcArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<BD> bdArrayList= new ArrayList<>();

        public void add(ArrayList<B> bArrayList) {
            for(B element : bArrayList) {
             if(element instanceof BC) {
                 bcArrayList.add((BC) element);
             } else if (element instanceof BD) {
                 bdArrayList.add((BD) element);
             } else {
                 continue;
             }
             }
        }
   }
```